# Select box to send to ajax code

Tags: ajax, select, drop-down-menu

I have been using a snippet of code to add data to a mysql database using ajax.I have this working perfectly using a text box to add, however I can't seem to get it working by replacing text box with select box.

Here is the original text box:

```html
 <form class="add-new-task" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="text" name="new-task" placeholder="Add a new item..." />
    </form>
```

Here is the code I have replaced it with:

```
<form class="add-new-task" autocomplete="off">
 <select name = "new-task">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
 </select>
   <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

Here is the receiving code:

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   function add_task() {
    $('.add-new-task').submit(function(){
    var new_task = $('.add-new-task input[name=new-task]').val();

    if(new_task != ''){
    $.post('add-task.php', { task: new_task }, function( data ) {
        $('.add-new-task input[name=new-task]').val('');
        $(data).appendTo('.task-list ul').hide().fadeIn();
                delete_task();
            });
    }
    return false; // Ensure that the form does not submit twice
    });
}

function delete_task() {
    $('.delete-button').click(function(){
    var current_element = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.post('delete-task.php', { task_id: id }, function() {
    current_element.parent().fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
    });
    });
}
```

I thought it would be simple and it probably is but I can't get it working,
Thanks in advance.

(Bill - Thanks for tidying it up)

Comment: `name = "new-task"` -> `name="new-task"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you replaced the input with select, below code needs to be changed

```
$('.add-new-task input[name=new-task]').val();
```

this should work

```
$('.add-new-task select[name=new-task]').val();
```